# Memory leak during in hibernate search

Tags: lucene, ehcache, hibernate-search

Greeting,

We are facing memory leak issue recently on one of our apps.

Development environment : Lucene2.4.0, hibernate search3.2.0, hibernate 3.5.0, spring2.5 and ehcache 1.4.1

The problem is that memory in old gen gradually goes up in a time period. Eventually, JVM runs out of memory as we see from jvm stats that old generation capacity reaches the maximum. As a result, I have to restart web to release all memory.

I generated a heap dump from app and use memory analyzer to check it. I see this:

```
123,726 instances of "org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosReader$ThreadResources", loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x7f5d71ffe3c8" occupy 3,139,449,272 (79.54%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment[]", loaded by "<system class loader>"
```

Can you give me some advices please?

thanks

Comment: Worth posting this to the Lucene users mailing list too, if you haven't done so already. http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/mailinglists.html

Comment: If you're using linux, try the command `jmap -histo:live <pid of your java process>` to check which objects are making RAM grow that high. Maybe you instantiate an Object containing many others that contain ConcurrentHashMap etc...

Comment: If it helps, I'm already moving to lucene 3.1 as I had memory problems, and there are known memory bugs using HibernateSearch